# Flask-Socketio emitting from an external process

Tags: python, flask, redis, flask-socketio

I've been working on a project using flask, flask-socketio and redis

I have a server, and some modules I would like to be able to emit from outside of the server file.

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request, json
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room, leave_room, emit

app = Flask(__name__)

socketio = SocketIO()

socketio.init_app(
    app, 
    cors_allowed_origins="*",
    message_que="redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"
)

@socketio.on('ready')
def ready(data):
    socketio.emit('rollCall', { 'message': 'Ive got work for you' }, room='Ready')
...
```

jobque.py

```
from modules.server.server import socketio

...

socketio.emit('rollCall', { 'message': 'Ive got work for you' }, room='Ready')
```

As it's currently configured, emits from the server file all work, the clients respond and they can talk back and forth. But when `jobque` goes to emit the same message, nothing happens. There's no error, and the client doesn't hear it.

I'm also using redis for things other than the websockets, I can get and set from it with no problem, in both files.

What do I need to do to get this external process to emit? I've looked through the `flask-socketio` documentation and this is exactly how they have it setup.

I've also tries creating a new SocketIO object inside `jobque.py` instead of importing the one form the server, but the results are the same

```
socket = SocketIO(message_queue="redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0")
socketio.emit('rollCall', { 'message': 'Ive got work for you' }, room='Ready')
```

I also went and checked if I could see the websocket traffic in redis with the message que setup using `redis-cli > MONITOR`, but I don't see any. I only see the operations I'm using redis for directly with the redis module. This makes me think the message que isn't actually being used, but I can't know for sure.

Comment: The argument in the server should be `message_queue`, not `message_que`. For the job queue process, you do need a separate `socketio` instance that is initialized without the `app` argument. That is what configures the object to work as an external emitter.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately spelled `message_queue` as `message_que` was the issue.
Creating a new SocketIO instance without the app works now.